# Facebook account is temporarily restricted due to unusual activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I am using Facebook Ads API to create Facebook ads, optimise them and fetch insights for users. Normal Facebook login flow is used to get the user access token and this access token is used to perform all the operations without exceeding the API limits.

But many of users' Facebook accounts are getting temporarily restricted.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?